# SQL to remove duplicated rows

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I've written a sql statement to only keep one instance (minimum id) where there are duplicated product_codes. The issue is that the statement is very inefficient and takes absolutely ages to run, so I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to write it

The dataset is structured as:

```
id  product_code  cat_desc      product_desc  
1   2352345       423           COCA COLA   
2   8967896       457           FANTA   
3   6456466       435           SPARKLING WATER 
4   3562314       457           STILL WATER
```

The statement is:

```
DELETE
FROM raw_products_inter
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM raw_products_inter outer_table
             WHERE product_code IN (SELECT product_code
                                    FROM raw_products_inter
                                    GROUP BY 1
                                    HAVING COUNT(id) > 1)
             AND   id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id)
                              FROM raw_products_inter inner_table
                              WHERE inner_table.product_code = outer_table.product_code))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to boost the performance using an EXISTS condition:

```
DELETE 
  FROM raw_products_inter P
 WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT *
            FROM raw_products_inter OP
           WHERE OP.product_code = P.product_code
             AND OP.id < P.id
       )
```

Comment: what an elegant solution, thanks. my original query I had to kill after an hour of running and this ran in 5 seconds :)